# Sharepoint list internal name creation policy

Tags: sharepoint, listfield

i have a list lets call it as

List1
in List1 list i have fields like the following

```
List1
  ID
  Title
```

....
also i have List2 and its columns like the following

```
List2
 ID
 Title
 Type
```

now i added a lookup field from List2 to List1 and now my List1 columns becomes

```
 List1
  ID
  Title
  List2
  List2:Title
```

when i look at the List2:Title i see its internal name is List2_x003a_Title

i easily can understand that ':' is represented as *x003a*
ie the hex code of ':' is *x003a*

after than i deleted column and readded it. oooooo
what i see is that the field added with the same external name but this time its INTERNAL NAME

List2_x003A_Title

can someone explain the reason. when the hex code is *x003a* or *x003A*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint internal name creation policy: the name is *encoded* to a valid XML name according to the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/).

Any XML name character that does not conform to the [XML 1.0 spec (fourth edition) recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/) is escaped as `_xHHHH_`. The `HHHH` string stands for the four-digit hexadecimal `UCS-2` code for the character in most significant bit first order. For example, the name `Order Details` is encoded as `Order_x0020_Details`.

.NET Framework contains [XmlConvert.EncodeName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodename.aspx) that converts the name to a valid XML name. This method guarantees the name is valid according to the XML specification.

Example:

```
var fieldName = XmlConvert.EncodeName("Order Details");  //returns Order_x0020_Details
```

Comment: but you didnot mention about why it comverts the : char to x003A in second run while in first run it was x003a